# SSRS 2008 - Count instances of a returned result

Tags: reporting-services, count, ssrs-2008

In SSRS I need to identify how many times a Driver logs onto a system between user specified dates - I already have the report displaying `[Driver] "LoggedOn at" [TimeOn] "Logged off at" [TimeOff] "for a duration of" [TimeOff-TimeOn]` (a bit more to it than that but thats the bones).

The resulting report looks like this and works fine:

```
David Niven logged on at .... for a duration of 3 hours

John Jones logged on at ... for a duration of 7 hours

David Niven logged on at ... for a duration of 5 hours

David Niven logged on at ... for a duration of 2 hours

Paul Newman logged on at .... for a duration of 3 hours etc etc
```

What I need to do is provide a summary - ie between the user specified dates

```
David Niven logged on 3 times for a total duration of 10 hours
John Jones logged on 1 time for a total duarion of 7 hours
Paul Newman logged on 1 time for a total duartion of 3 hours
```

Can I use an expression to add the number of times each driver logged on in SSRS 2008 and for how long ? - if so, how - can give more specific example of my query if needed ... many many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different queries, just using grouping and a sub-query:

```
DECLARE @driverInfo TABLE
(
    Name varchar(50),
    TimeOn datetime,
    TimeOff datetime
)

INSERT INTO @driverInfo
SELECT 'David Niven', '2013-07-23 09:00', '2013-07-23 12:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'John Jones', '2013-07-23 09:00', '2013-07-23 16:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'David Niven', '2013-07-23 13:00', '2013-07-23 18:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'David Niven', '2013-07-24 09:00', '2013-07-24 11:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Paul Newman', '2013-07-23 09:00', '2013-07-23 12:00'

-- used for first data set
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(hour, TimeOn, TimeOff) AS [TotalHours]
FROM @driverInfo

-- used for second data set
SELECT Name, COUNT(*), SUM(TotalHours)
FROM (
    SELECT Name, DATEDIFF(hour, TimeOn, TimeOff) AS [TotalHours]
    FROM @driverInfo
) S
GROUP BY S.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this at the report level off the same Dataset as the detail values, you can add an expression like this to a group header/footer:

```
=Fields!Driver.Value
  & " logged on "
  & CountRows()
  & " times for a total duration of "
  & Sum(DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, Fields!TimeOn.Value, Fields!TimeOff.Value))
  & " hours"
```

`CountRows` just gives the number of rows in the group, i.e. the number of logons, and you can sum the `DateDiff` values of each row in the group to get the total hours.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this suggestion?